# zip like function in Tensorflow? Tensorflow tensor operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

My question is about the tensor operation in Tensorflow. 
Let's say:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.Variable(np.random.random([10, 3, 3]))
b = tf.Variable(np.random.random([10, 3, 3]))

def some_function(m,n):
    # just as an example
    return tf.add(m, n)
```

This works in Tensorflow but it requires to know the dimension in advanced. However, it is very likely that the first dimension of the Tensor is None.

```
c = []
for i in range(10):
    c.append(some_function(a[i], b[i]))
c = tf.stack(c)
```

So I wonder if there is a zip-like function in Tensorflow? Then we can do:

```
# TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
c = []
for i, j in zip(a,b):
    c.append(some_function(i,j))
c = tf.stack(c)
```

Maybe we can use some function like tf.map_fn or tf.scan? But I am not sure. Really thank you, guys.

Comment: For loops are seldom used in TensorFlow especially dealing with tensors computation because the loop is in python and would be slow compared with internal c++, there are very likely to exist functions or ops in TensorFlow that can do you task more mathematically without loops.

Answer (score 11):

Tensor objects are not iterable, which explains why your third code sample fails. So, to answer your question, there is no zip-like function in TensorFlow.

You can indeed use [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) to apply a function to a sequence of tensors. The problem you pose in your example code can be solved in the following fashion:

```
def some_function(tensor):
  return tf.reduce_sum(tensor)

c = tf.stack([a, b], axis=1)
d = tf.map_fn(some_function, c, dtype=tf.float32)
```

yields a Tensor `d` whose value is `[20., 6., 6.]`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `tf.transpose` like this

```py
>>> a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = tf.constant([4, 5, 6])
>>> tf.transpose([a, b])
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]], dtype=int32)>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using JavsScript, this is @bachr's answer in tensorflow.js (node):

```
const a =  tf.tensor([1, 3, 5, 7])
const b = tf.tensor([2, 4, 6, 8])
const zip = tf.transpose(tf.stack([a, b]))
zip.print()
// Tensor
//    [[1, 2],
//     [3, 4],
//     [5, 6],
//     [7, 8]]
```